# Unable to load data from Json file

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, http

What i'm trying to do is create an image grid layout. Similar to this but in each box is a photo which is loaded from a json file via a HTTP.get

[image]

I'm trying to create the grid layout by creating the first row and then using `ng-repeat` so it creates new rows.

I'm retrieving my images from a `$http.get` request which loads the images via a JSON file.

I cannot get the images to display and i'm unsure why. I have no errors in my console log.

This is my HTML code so far.

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="" ng-if="$index % 1 === 0">
  <div class="col col-33" ng-if="$index < length">
    <img ng-src="{{image.image}}">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your not seeing any images is because your not accessing your data properly in your HTML. Try this:

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="image in data.under9s">
<div id="container" class="col col-33" ng-if="$index < data.under9s.length">
    <img class="image image-list-thumb" id="image" ng-src="{{image.image}}" />
</div>
<div id="container" class="col col-33" ng-if="$index + 1 < data.under9s.length">
    <img class="image image-list-thumb" id="image" ng-src="{{data.under9s[$index + 1].image}}" />
</div>
<div id="container" class="col col-33" ng-if="$index + 2 < data.under9s.length">
    <img class="image image-list-thumb" id="image" ng-src="{{data.under9s[$index + 2].image}}" />
</div>
```

I think you could easily accomplish your grid using two ng-repeats. Something like:

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="category in data">
    <div ng-repeat="image in category" id="container" class="col col-33">
        <img class="image image-list-thumb" id="image" ng-src="{{image.image}}" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

That is security issue. Either use `jsonp` or `CORS`.

Comment: You sure?  I have set it up from this tutorial a few weeks ago and used a http.get with a json file to input the data and it worked. I'm not sure why it isn't working now. https://blog.nraboy.com/2015/03/make-a-gallery-like-image-grid-using-ionic-framework/